# how to disable editing in a textbox and how to set default value of text box is eql to session variable

Tags: php

I am editing a page and there i am asking again username and password for confirmation..
I want to pick username from session variable

```
$_SESSION['employee']['password']=$row['Password'];
```

and want that username displayed there(i am setting username box value=session username variable) but not for editing only password is asked with value blank..

HOw i disable editing of any textbox like when we choose settings in orkut ...

I am trying this thing

```
<td><b><i>Username</i></b></td>
<td><input type="text" id="username" value="<?php $_SESSION['employee']['password'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

But by doing this my username textbox again coming blank.It is not filled with username i think the syntex i am using wrong...

```
value="<?php $_SESSION['employee']['password'] ?>"
```

How i can correct it..

Answer (score 1):

use `<?=$SOMETHING?>` or `<?php echo($SOMETHING); ?>`.

Comment: And use htmlspecialchars() on your text: http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['employee']['password']; ?>" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: can i send disabled text box value to the next page like simple text boxes through post or get .For example value="<?php echo $_SESSION['employee']['password']; ?>" disabled="disabled" How i will send this value to next page.In simple it is not occuring

Answer (score 0):

you need to print or echo the session variable.